# Question about scaled models of compressors and turbines

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, compressible-flow

Hello I am an engineering student and I have some questions about scaled models for compressors and turbines:

1. When building scaled models of compressors or turbines to analysis
   them, what coefficients are the same between a scaled model and real
   prototype?
2. How should we compare a scaled model and a real prototype? What does
   "scaled" mean? Does a one quarter model for a turbine means the
   geometry dimensions of model are 1/4 of a real prototype?
3. How could we do analysis if a question provides a different spin
   speed for scaled model and real prototype?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to decide if you are going for kinematic similarity, dynamic or geometric.

That depends on what you want to test, so you might design a 1/10 model and keep the Re the same or the velocity ratio. Or you could be using water to replace air as the working fluid since the density ratio is about 1000.

All depends on what results you want and which you can ignore, or sacrifice, for the job in hand.

Check out Dimensional Analysis: two names here Rayleigh and Buckingham - that will give you some stuff to read

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Your suggestion is really helpful!

Comment: Just a comment in general about modeling, whether physical or mathematical: the whole point of modeling something is to simplify it in some way, to get rid of variables, and to find out what you need to about just one aspect of the thing you're modeling.  So the **absolute key to modeling** is that you're throwing away fidelity in some area (to make the model easier to build or easier to understand), while retaining fidelity in the area you care about.  So you really need to understand what you're modeling, and what you want out of the model.